# Edit Text in list duplicated data while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I'm having this issue: while list view recycles the views it duplicates the data inserted in the edit text and I only need from edit texts not to be duplicated so that I'll get the correct quantity. I tried not recycling the views but that deleted the values when I scroll down.

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article>
{


    public  static List<Livraison_detail> MAJdb=new ArrayList<Livraison_detail>();;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    List<Article> articles=null;
    String []qtes;

    public ArticleAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Article> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        articles=new ArrayList<>(objects);
        qtes=new String[articles.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        viewHolder= new ViewHolder();

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater infalter=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView=infalter.inflate(R.layout.list_view_article,parent,false);


            viewHolder.designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desi);
            viewHolder.quantité = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte_disp_2);
            viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix);
            viewHolder.qte=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte);
            viewHolder.cb=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbarticle);



            viewHolder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CheckBox check=(CheckBox)view;
                    check.requestFocus();
                    if (check.isChecked())
                    {
                        Article a =articles.get((int)check.getTag());
                        Livraison_detail l=new Livraison_detail();
                        l.CODE_ARTICLE=a.CODE_ARTICLE;
                        l.PRIX_ACHAT=a.PRIX_VENTE;
                        try
                        {
                            if(qtes[(int)check.getTag()].equals(""))
                            {
                                throw new Exception();
                            }else {
                                if (Double.parseDouble(qtes[(int)check.getTag()])>a.QTE_CHARGE) throw  new QuantitéInsuffisanteException();
                                else{
                                    l.QTE_LIVRE=Double.parseDouble(qtes[(int)check.getTag()]);
                                    MAJdb.add(l);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (QuantitéInsuffisanteException e)
                        {
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                    .setTitle("Quantité Insuffisante")
                                    .setMessage("la quantité saisie est superieur que celle du Stock il y a "+a.QTE_CHARGE+" artcile Disp")
                                    .setCancelable(true)
                                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                                    .setNeutralButton("Compris",null )
                                    .show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Il faut toucher le fin bouton du clavier puis re-cochez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Article a2=articles.get((int)check.getTag());

                        for (Livraison_detail l:MAJdb) {
                            if (l.CODE_ARTICLE.equals(a2.CODE_ARTICLE))
                            {
                                MAJdb.remove(l);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            viewHolder.qte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final int position = view.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) view;
                    qtes[position]=Caption.getText().toString();
                    if(Caption.isFocused()) {Caption.clearFocus();}
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.cbarticle, viewHolder.cb);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.qte, viewHolder.qte);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.qte.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.qte.setId(position);



        Article article=articles.get(position);
        if(article !=null)
        {
            viewHolder.designation.setText(article.DESIGNATION);
            viewHolder.prix.setText(Double.toString(article.PRIX_VENTE));
            viewHolder.quantité.setText(Integer.toString(article.QTE_CHARGE));
        }


        return convertView;
    }



    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView designation;
        TextView quantité;
        TextView prix;
        EditText qte;
        CheckBox cb;
    }


}
```

Comment: listview  replace recyclerview use then ease to avoid duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to compile your code to check the mistake. But looking on it I can make two suggestinos:

1. Storing of separate `ViewHolder` for each **position**;
2. Do not use `View.setTag()` method to store a **position** value;

   ```
   public static List<Livraison_detail> MAJdb = new ArrayList<Livraison_detail>();

   private SparseArray<ViewHolder> map = new SparseArray<>();
   List<Article> articles = null;
   String[] qtes;

   public ArticleAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Article> objects) {
       super(context, resource, objects);
       articles = new ArrayList<>(objects);
       qtes = new String[articles.size()];
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder viewHolder;

       if (convertView == null) {
           viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
           LayoutInflater infalter = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           convertView = infalter.inflate(R.layout.list_view_article, parent, false);


           viewHolder.designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desi);
           viewHolder.quantité = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte_disp_2);
           viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix);
           viewHolder.qte = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte);
           viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbarticle);


           viewHolder.cb.setOnClickListener(
                   new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view;
                           check.requestFocus();
                           if (check.isChecked()) {
                               Article a = articles.get(position);
                               Livraison_detail l = new Livraison_detail();
                               l.CODE_ARTICLE = a.CODE_ARTICLE;
                               l.PRIX_ACHAT = a.PRIX_VENTE;
                               try {
                                   if (qtes[position].equals("")) {
                                       throw new Exception();
                                   } else {
                                       if (Double.parseDouble(qtes[position]) > a.QTE_CHARGE) {
                                           throw new QuantitéInsuffisanteException();
                                       } else {
                                           l.QTE_LIVRE = Double.parseDouble(qtes[position]);
                                           MAJdb.add(l);
                                       }
                                   }
                               } catch (QuantitéInsuffisanteException e) {
                                   new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                           .setTitle("Quantité Insuffisante")
                                           .setMessage("la quantité saisie est superieur que celle du Stock il y a " + a.QTE_CHARGE + " artcile Disp")
                                           .setCancelable(true)
                                           .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                                           .setNeutralButton("Compris", null)
                                           .show();
                               } catch (Exception e) {
                                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Il faut toucher le fin bouton du clavier puis re-cochez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                           } else {
                               Article a2 = articles.get(position);

                               for (Livraison_detail l : MAJdb) {
                                   if (l.CODE_ARTICLE.equals(a2.CODE_ARTICLE)) {
                                       MAJdb.remove(l);
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   });

           viewHolder.qte.setOnClickListener(
                   new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           final int position = view.getId();
                           final EditText Caption = (EditText) view;
                           qtes[position] = Caption.getText().toString();
                           if (Caption.isFocused()) {
                               Caption.clearFocus();
                           }
                       }
                   });

           map.put(position, viewHolder);
           convertView.setTag(R.id.cbarticle, viewHolder.cb);
           convertView.setTag(R.id.qte, viewHolder.qte);
       } else {
           viewHolder = map.get(position);
       }

       viewHolder.qte.setTag(position);
       viewHolder.cb.setTag(position);
       viewHolder.qte.setId(position);


       Article article = articles.get(position);
       if (article != null) {
           viewHolder.designation.setText(article.DESIGNATION);
           viewHolder.prix.setText(Double.toString(article.PRIX_VENTE));
           viewHolder.quantité.setText(Integer.toString(article.QTE_CHARGE));
       }


       return convertView;
   }


   private class ViewHolder {
       TextView designation;
       TextView quantité;
       TextView prix;
       EditText qte;
       CheckBox cb;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much but now but now i can't get an get the objects to display or to even retrieve text from edittexts i only get null pointer exceptions

Comment: thank u all i solved the problem using getViewTypeCount

Comment: @YacineBenKaidAli if you found my answer useful, please vote it and mark as the answer on your question. I will be grateful for that.

Answer (score 0):

try this...i have modified your getView() method
hope this will help you

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    viewHolder= new ViewHolder();

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater infalter=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView=infalter.inflate(R.layout.list_view_article,parent,false);


        viewHolder.designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desi);
        viewHolder.quantité = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte_disp_2);
        viewHolder.prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix);
        viewHolder.qte=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qte);
        viewHolder.cb=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbarticle);





        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else {
        viewHolder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox check=(CheckBox)view;
                check.requestFocus();
                if (check.isChecked())
                {
                    Article a =articles.get((int)check.getTag());
                    Livraison_detail l=new Livraison_detail();
                    l.CODE_ARTICLE=a.CODE_ARTICLE;
                    l.PRIX_ACHAT=a.PRIX_VENTE;
                    try
                    {
                        if(qtes[(int)check.getTag()].equals(""))
                        {
                            throw new Exception();
                        }else {
                            if (Double.parseDouble(qtes[(int)check.getTag()])>a.QTE_CHARGE) throw  new QuantitéInsuffisanteException();
                            else{
                                l.QTE_LIVRE=Double.parseDouble(qtes[(int)check.getTag()]);
                                MAJdb.add(l);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (QuantitéInsuffisanteException e)
                    {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                                .setTitle("Quantité Insuffisante")
                                .setMessage("la quantité saisie est superieur que celle du Stock il y a "+a.QTE_CHARGE+" artcile Disp")
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                                .setNeutralButton("Compris",null )
                                .show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Il faut toucher le fin bouton du clavier puis re-cochez", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Article a2=articles.get((int)check.getTag());

                    for (Livraison_detail l:MAJdb) {
                        if (l.CODE_ARTICLE.equals(a2.CODE_ARTICLE))
                        {
                            MAJdb.remove(l);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.qte.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int position = view.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) view;
                qtes[position]=Caption.getText().toString();
                if(Caption.isFocused()) {Caption.clearFocus();}
            }
        });

    Article article=articles.get(position);
    if(article !=null)
    {
        viewHolder.designation.setText(article.DESIGNATION);
        viewHolder.prix.setText(Double.toString(article.PRIX_VENTE));
        viewHolder.quantité.setText(Integer.toString(article.QTE_CHARGE));
    }


    return convertView;
}



private class ViewHolder
{
    TextView designation;
    TextView quantité;
    TextView prix;
    EditText qte;
    CheckBox cb;
}
```